# how to pass a validation from php to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

**How can I make my error messages appear after validation in PHP using AJAX**

Hi, I'm currently working on my ajax and I'm tryng to figure out on how will my error message appear on my form. I've already tried to echo the error but what I want is show the error on every invalid field.

here's my html code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        span{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test2.php" method="POST" id="formLogin" class="pass">
        name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <span id="name">Invalid!</span> 
        <br>
        description: <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
        <span id="desc">Invalid!</span>
        <br>
        image file: <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
        <button type="submit"  ></button>
    </form><br>
    <p class="form-message"></p>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
```

heres my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#formLogin").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test2.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    if(data.name == "1"){
                        $("span#name").css("display","block");
                    }else{
                        $("span#name").css("display","none");
                    }
                    if(data.desc == "1"){
                        $("span#desc").css("display","block");
                    }else{
                        $("span#desc").css("display","none");
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

and my php code;

```
<?php
    $myObj = new stdClass();


    if(empty($_POST['name'])){
        $myObj->name = "1";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['description'])){
        $myObj->description = "1";
    }

    $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

    echo $myJSON;
?>
```

Comment: this works for me. thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In success of ajax, you receive the data in json formate , before use the `data.name` you have to reqiure parse json like
        `data=$.parseJSON(data)` OR `data=JSON.parseJSON(data)`
        then use `data.name`